# (Statistics) How do I find the Average, Median & Mode for abstract data?

Tags: statistics

Say I have this table:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
║OS         ║ Frequency ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
║Windows    ║       41  ║
║Mac OSX    ║        7  ║
║Linux      ║        2  ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

How do I extract Average, Median & Mode for it? To get the average I would have to get data from the first column divided by the sum of the frequency column, however, there's no way to add up abstract data.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a interval scaled variable. In this case we have to assume that the difference of the utilities of the operation systems are constant. 

$x_i=\begin{cases} 0, \texttt{if the operating system of user i is  Windows}\\ 1, \texttt{if the operating system of user i is Mac OSX}\\2, \texttt{if the operating system of user i is Linux} \end{cases}$

Comment: I thought about that. Would that be right though? 0+1+2= 3/50 so the average is 0,06? @callculus

Comment: No,  the average is $\overline x=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} x_i}{50}=\frac1{50}\cdot (\underbrace{0+0+0+\ldots}_{\text{41 times}}+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+2+2)=\frac{1}{50}\cdot (7\cdot 1+2\cdot 2)$. The result has to be rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: But it depends how you interpretate the result. You can say that the average user uses Windows. But you cannot say that on average the OS is Windows.

Comment: So the average is 0.22 and the median is 0, right? Wonder if the teacher will accept that as correct. @callculus

Comment: As I said it depends on the exact question.  The nearest integer of 0.22 is 0. You can say that the average user uses Windows. What are the explanatory notes to the table ? Without any notes the table is useless. Yes the median is 0.

Comment: There is no explanatory notes, it provides the data and say I should extract the average, median a mode. There's no catch, that's that. I'll say that since it's qualitative there's no average & median, however, you can extract them by using interval scaled variable and replacing etc.. I wonder. @callculus

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question. The only thing you can say for sure that the mode is the Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there's no way to add abstract data.

Thus, statistical numerical values like average or median are not defined for samples of a qualitative variable (in this case, the OS). However, mode is not numerical, it is simply the data element with the higher frequency.

For example, imagine you wanted to study the favorite ice cream flavor of the people of your neighbourhood. You couldn't calculate the average flavor they like, but you can tell what's the most popular flavor.

In your case, there is no average nor median. However, the mode is Windows, because it is the OS with the highest frequency.

Comment: Just as I suspected, thanks for clearing it up. The assignment asks me to calculate it though, I'll say it's impossible.